# Why does a negative value give segmentation fault for the program which is to find pairs of value from the array which has the given sum?

Tags: c, hash, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

void findpairs(int arr[], int arr_size, int sum)
{
  int i, temp;
  int hash[100] = {0}; 

  for(i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
  {
    temp = sum - arr[i];
    if(hash[temp] == 1)
    {
      printf("Pair with given sum %d is (%d, %d) \n", sum, arr[i], temp);
    }
    hash[arr[i]] = 1;
  }
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = {4,-4,9,2,1,6,5,11};
    int sum =7;
    int arr_size = 8;
    findpairs(A, arr_size, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

[link to the same program](http://codepad.org/Sou55dvI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash[arr[i]] = 1;
...
hash[-4] = 1;
```

Your `hash` array has indices from 0 to 99, so you're accessing out-of-bounds data.

Your next out-of-bounds access will be for the value 9,

```
temp = 7 - 9;
if (hash[temp] == 1)
```

Comment: If you change it to `hash[(arr[i]+100)%100] = 1;` you'll be able to handle negative numbers up to -100, but you may have a hash collision with positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Because trying to access a negative index is bad.

```
temp = sum - arr[i];
if(hash[temp] == 1)
```

or

```
hash[arr[i]] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

> `temp = sum - arr[i]`

What if `sum < arr [i]`? `hash[temp] == 1` would segfault on most implementations.

Similar behaviour in case of `hash[arr[i]] = 1;` if `arr[i]` is negative.

Technically speaking accessing out of bound array element invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: How can I solve this problem as in how can I store the values of negative index in hash?

Comment: @imaginatives: You can't directly use negative array index. As Null Set has suggested under Erik's answer you need to employ some modular arithmetic machinery. :)